# Animation problems persist

Tags: python, animation, pygame

## The code

```
#Importing files/modules
import pygame
import random

#Colors

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
ORANGe = (255, 115, 0)
YELLOW = (242, 255, 0)
BROWN = (115, 87, 39)
PURPLE = ( 298, 0, 246)
GRAY = ( 168, 168, 168)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
GROUND = (156,168,91)
pygame.init()

#Screen
screenx = 1000
screeny = 700
screentotal = [screenx,screeny]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screentotal)

#Caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Animation attempt one")

#Variables
x = 500
y = 1000
a = 0
b = 500
c = 1500
d = 1000
#Booleans
go = True
#Graphics
one = pygame.image.load("uno.jpg").convert()
two = pygame.image.load("dos.jpg").convert()
three = pygame.image.load("tres.jpg").convert()

#Position
position = [0,0]
#Time management
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
animation_timer = pygame.time.Clock()
animation_time = 0
screen.fill(GREEN)
#MAIN LOOP _________________________________________________________

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True



    if go:
        animation_timer.tick()
        animation_time += animation_timer.get_time()
        if animation_time < x and  animation_time > a:
            screen.blit(one,position)
            x += 1000
            a += 1000
        if animation_time < y and animation_time> b:
            screen.blit(two,position)
            y += 1000
            b += 1000
        if animation_time < c and animation_time > d:
            screen.blit(three,position)
            c += 1000
            d += 1000






    #Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
#Quit
pygame.quit()
```

## The Problem

My code is supposed to draw 3 images in an animation, and incrementally add the abcd to make it loop in an animation. When I just do it with the two first images in the if statements it works fine. But when I add the 3rd if image statement, it shows the animation by displaying 3 images every have seconds, however after the first time it animates the 3rd image does not pop up and only the first 2 images work. I have tried changing the timing and the variables but it doesn't work.

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

I know this is a very complicated way of trying to animate, but it's the way I like best. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to happen. This is a very confusing way to go about animation things.

Comment: I want the 3 images to blit every half second however the previous image will dissapear and then appear when the loop restarts. Im just having problems with my 3rd image showing up once and then never coming back. I like making animation's this way, I know there are other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. Turns out due to the amount of events, I had to increment the last image by 2000 not 1000. So c and d need to be added by 2000 not 1000.